# Use Swift @propertyWrapper for dynamic default value?

Tags: swift, swift5, property-wrapper

I need a Swift property that -- if the value has not yet been set -- defaults to another value.

This *can* be implemented using backing-store private properties. For instance, for a property `num` that should default to a global `defaultNum`, it would work something like this:

```
var defaultNum = 1

class MyClass {
  var num: Int {
    get { _num ?? defaultNum }
    set { _num = newValue }
   }

  private var _num: Int?
}

let c = MyClass()
print("initial \(c.num)") // == 1 ✅

// changing the default changes the value returned
defaultNum = 2
print("dynamic \(c.num)") // == 2 ✅

// once the property is set, returns the stored value
c.num = 5
print("base    \(c.num)") // == 5 ✅
```

That works, but for a common pattern in our code, it's a lot of boilerplate for each such property.

**Using Swift property wrappers, is it possible to do this more concisely?**

---

#### What *won't* work

Note that, because we expect the default to be dynamic, static initializers will not work. For example:

```
var defaultNum = 1

class MyClass {
  var num = defaultNum
}

var c = MyClass()
defaultNum = 2
print(c.num) // this == 1, we want the current value of defaultNum, which == 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by creating a property wrapper like this:

```
@propertyWrapper
public struct Default<T> {
  var baseValue: T?
  var closure: () -> T

  // this allows a nicer syntax for single variables...
  public init(_ closure: @autoclosure @escaping () -> T) {
    self.closure = closure
  }

  // ... and if we want to explicitly use a closure, we can.
  public init(_ closure: @escaping () -> T) {
    self.closure = closure
  }

  public var wrappedValue: T {
    get { baseValue ?? closure() }
    set { baseValue = newValue }
  }
}
```

You then use the `@Default` property wrapper on a property like this:

```
var defaultNum = 1

class MyClass {
  @Default(defaultNum)
  var num: Int
}
```

You'd then see the following in practice:

```
let c = MyClass()

// if we haven't set the property yet, it uses the closure to return a default value
print("initial \(c.num)") // == 1 ✅

// because we are using a closure, changing the default changes the value returned
defaultNum = 2
print("dynamic \(c.num)") // == 2 ✅

// once the property is set, uses the stored base value
c.num = 5
print("base    \(c.num)") // == 5 ✅
```